# Explicitly loading all navigation properties in a list of previously fetched objects in Entity Framework?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, loading, explicit

Suppose I have something like

```
 var remoteData = query.Where(s => <conditions here>).ToArray();
```

and every object in the array has a navigation property called `Department`.

Is there a way of explicitly loading all the `Department` properties in a single query to the SQL server.

Doing something like this results in numerous queries

```
remoteData.ForEach(rd =>
{
    rd.DepartmentReference.Load();
});
```

I know about `Include` but that is too slow. I want to load everything after the filtering takes place.

Comment: I believe that calling ToArray forces the load anyway, in your case.  If you just want the department itself, you can use object initialization.

Comment: @Mr.B can you explain in a bit more detail please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, if you want to get data faster, you should select releted entities in separate query like this:

```
var deps = dbContext.DepartmentReference.Where(o=>...).ToDictionary(o=>o.DataID);
```

Here you can join this query on your `query` not to repeat condition.

And then set values:

```
remoteData.ForEach(rd =>
{
    rd.DepartmentReference = deps[rd.ID];
});
```

Comment: This produces the same query as Include set before the where which I tried but is too slow.

Comment: @Para my fault, i changed answer

Comment: Why is there a .ToArray() after depts[rd.ID]? DocumentReference is supposed to reference an object not an array

Comment: @Para I thought, it's a collection, so updated answer

Comment: Thank you very much, this seems to work. But won't this cause problems on update operations. Won't it break EF's referencing system? I am just asking :). I figure you are replacing an entity with another entity even if they have the same id and point to the same entry in the database.

Comment: @Para no, it's ok, these entities are from the same context, so EF controls this